# How to login user with phone number and password in laravel using rest api?

Tags: laravel, rest, api

> hi I'm new to web development with laravel. I'm building a user authentication webapp that accepts phone number/email and password during login. so i used the code below to override how my credentials are authenticated on the web. this way both phone number and emails are accepted during login on the web but i want to apply the same logic to a rest api. 
>   how do I go about this?

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    if(is_numeric($request->get('email'))){
        return ['phone'=>$request->get('email'),'password'=>$request->get('password')];
    }
    elseif (filter_var($request->get('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')];
    }
    return ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you should use jwt to implement rest api authentication check the link below:

https://medium.com/employbl/build-authentication-into-your-laravel-api-with-json-web-tokens-jwt-cd223ace8d1a